# Traverse multiple nodes Cypher query Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am working with a [meetup dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/sirpunch/meetups-data-from-meetupcom/version/1) and I want to get members data, in particular, I am interested in lat and lon fields. At the same time, I would like to get groups names and venues locations (lat and on).
I have created such Neo4j query, however, it doesn't return anything:

```
MATCH (m)-[mtg_r:MT_TO_MEMBER_CSV]->(mt)-[mtt_r:MT_TO_TOPIC_CSV]->(t)-[tt_r:GT_TO_TOPIC_CSV]->(gt)-[tg_r:GT_TO_GROUP_CSV]->(g)-[h_r:HAS_CSV]->(e)-[a_r:AT_CSV]->(v)
RETURN mt.member_id,t.topic_name, gt.topic_id , v.lat, v.lon, e.event_name
```

Although if I will delete Members entity traversal and change it in such a way, I can get the data:

```
MATCH (mt)-[mtt_r:MT_TO_TOPIC_CSV]->(t)-[tt_r:GT_TO_TOPIC_CSV]->(gt)-[tg_r:GT_TO_GROUP_CSV]->(g)-[h_r:HAS_CSV]->(e)-[a_r:AT_CSV]->(v)
RETURN mt.member_id,t.topic_name, gt.topic_id , v.lat, v.lon, e.event_name
```

The problem is that I need to traverse practically all the nodes in my dataset. Here is a database schema:
[image]

In my query, I need to find events for members by their location and groups by the topics they are interested in.
So how should I change the query to traverse all the necessary nodes and get the information I need?

UPDATE:
This is how I created relationships:

```
MATCH (e:EventCSV),(v:VenueCSV) WHERE e.venue_id=v.venue_id CREATE (e)-[a_r:AT_CSV]->(v);
MATCH (e:EventCSV),(g:GroupCSV) WHERE g.group_id=e.group_id CREATE (g)-[h_r:HAS_CSV]->(e);
MATCH (m:MemberCSV),(g:GroupCSV) WHERE m.group_id=g.group_id CREATE (m)-[pi_r:PARTICIPATE_IN_CSV]->(g);
MATCH (g:GroupCSV),(gt:GroupTopicsCSV) WHERE gt.group_id=g.group_id CREATE (gt)-[tg_r:GT_TO_GROUP_CSV]->(g);
MATCH (t:TopicCSV),(gt:GroupTopicsCSV) WHERE t.topic_id=gt.topic_id CREATE (t)-[tt_r:GT_TO_TOPIC_CSV]->(gt);
MATCH (m:MemberCSV),(mt:MemberTopicsCSV) WHERE m.member_id=mt.member_id CREATE (m)-[mtg_r:MT_TO_MEMBER_CSV]->(mt);
MATCH (t:TopicCSV),(mt:MemberTopicsCSV) WHERE t.topic_id=mt.topic_id CREATE (mt)-[mtt_r:MT_TO_TOPIC_CSV]->(t);
MATCH p=()-[r:AT_CSV]->() RETURN count(p);
```

Tables import:

```
CREATE (e:EventCSV { event_id: toInteger(line.event_id), created: line.created, description: line.description, duration: toInteger(line.duration),event_url: line.event_url, group_created: line.`group.created`, group_lat: toFloat(line.`group.group_lat`), group_lon: toFloat(line.`group.group_lon`), group_id: toInteger(line.`group_id`), group_join_mode: line.`group.join_mode`, group_name: line.`group.name`, event_name: line.event_name, photo_url: line.photo_url, event_time: line.event_time, venue_address_2: line.`venue.address_2`, venue_city: line.`venue.city`, venue_country: line.`venue.country`, venue_id: toInteger(line.venue_id), venue_lat: toFloat(line.`venue.lat`), venue_lon: toFloat(line.`venue.lon`), venue_name: line.`venue.name`, yes_rsvp_count: toInteger(line.yes_rsvp_count)});
CREATE (v:VenueCSV { venue_id: toInteger(line.venue_id), address_1: line.address_1, city: line.city, country: line.country, lat: toFloat(line.lat), lon: toFloat(line.lon), venue_name: line.venue_name, rating: toFloat(line.rating)});
CREATE (g:GroupCSV { group_id: toInteger(line.group_id), category_name: line.`category.name`, city: line.city, country: line.country, created: line.created, description: line.description, join_mode: line.join_mode, lat: toFloat(line.lat), link: line.link, lon: toFloat(line.lon), members: toInteger(line.members), group_name: line.group_name, organizer_name: line.`organizer.name`, rating: toFloat(line.rating)});
CREATE (m: MemberCSV { member_id: toInteger(line.member_id), bio: line.bio, city: line.city, country: line.country, joined: line.joined, lat: toFloat(line.lat), link: line.link, lon: toFloat(line.lon), member_name: line.member_name, member_status: line.member_status, group_id: toInteger(line.group_id)});
CREATE (t:TopicCSV { topic_id: toInteger(line.topic_id), description: line.description, link: line.link, members: toInteger(line.members), topic_name: line.`topic_name`, main_topic_id: toInteger(line.main_topic_id)});
CREATE (gt:GroupTopicsCSV { topic_id: toInteger(line.topic_id), topic_name: line.`topic_name`, group_id: toInteger(line.group_id)});
CREATE (mt:MemberTopicsCSV { topic_id: toInteger(line.topic_id), topic_name: line.`topic_name`,member_id: toInteger(line.member_id)});
```

UPDATE: Tables connections in Neo4j added
[image]

Comment: Seems that you does not have any `:MT_TO_MEMBER_CSV` relationship followed by a `:MT_TO_TOPIC_CSV` relationship...

Comment: Maybe you should share your import script.

Comment: @BrunoPeres I added how I imported relationships and tables

Comment: You can check how your nodes are connected (labels connected by relationship types) with `CALL db.schema()` (or `CALL apoc.meta.graph()` if you have APOC Procedures installed). That should help you confirm how your data is connected

Comment: Also you really should be using labels in your query, at least for one of the nodes in that path. Your query right now has to do an all nodes scan and expand to try to find where to start. Do a PROFILE on the query (the query that works) to confirm.

Comment: @InverseFalcon thanks for an advice. I have added my schema to the question